# How do I use 'at' on a wireless Mac?

Tags: keyboard

I have paired a Mac wireless keyboard with my PC. It works well but being an unfamiliar Mac user I don't know how to use the <kbd>@</kbd> symbol which is spaced above the 2. If I use shift it actually puts in the Euro sign (<kbd>€</kbd>) instead. Can anyone help me **find a way to make the <kbd>@</kbd> sign with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>?**

Comment: Are you using a *Mac* or a *Windows PC* with your Apple wireless keyboard?

Comment: @aliasgar - The comment above raises an issue about whether the question concerns a Mac computer or Mac keyboard on a Windows PC.  Adding a [mac] tag without having clarification can harm the question by imposing a potentially wrong assumption or mindset on people who answer.

Comment: @fixer1234 corrected the error, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

Your keyboard is not configured to US ANSI which is default. You are asked to confirm by pressing the left and right <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys on the keyboard when you boot your Mac for the first time.

This is what I get:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> = `@`
2. <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> = `™`
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> = `€` (This is what you get on <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>)

**What you should be doing is:**

- Go to System Preferences, then click Keyboard, and then Change Keyboard Type.
- Alternately what I get in 3 above, that is the `€` should get you the `@`, applying vice-verse logic.

**If you're using a Mac Keyboard on a Windows PC:**

- Your keyboard is definitely on a wrong configuration.
- Or Windows had loaded a wrong driver, and it's not on US ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

An [interesting table here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA26547?viewlocale=en_US) shows you what you *should* be using to get the €. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, however, is not on the list which, as @aliasgar pointed out, points to the wrong keyboard type being selected.

[image]